Delete function not able to delete elements by ID
I am learning js and to practice what I have learnt, I am building a todo list. It has a delete button that deletes a list item. It deletes the element by it's ID which I automatically generate using incrementation. However, it deletes all elements regardless of their id and then throws off a null error.
I have spent almost 2 hours on the problem, trying every approach. I will be grateful if you could help me.


let store = [];
let store_len = -1;
let auto_id = 0

function fetchList() {
  store_len++;
  let user_input = document.querySelector(".input").value;
  let date_input = document.querySelector(".date").value
  store[store_len] = {
    TODO: user_input,
    Date: date_input
  };
  document.querySelector(".div").innerHTML = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
    auto_id++;
    html = `<div id="${auto_id}">${store[i].TODO}</div>
              <div id="${auto_id}">${store[i].Date}</div>
              <button id="${auto_id}" onclick='
              store.splice(${i}, 1);
              document.querySelector(".grid").innerHTML = "";
              store_len--;
              document.getElementById("${auto_id}").remove();
              '>Delete</button>`
    document.querySelector(".div").innerHTML += html
  };
};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
    <style>
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 15% 10% 5%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <p>Todo list</p>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Todo name">
  <input type="date" class="date">
  <button onclick="fetchList();">Add</button>
  <div class="div grid"></div>
  <script src="TODOjs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




onclick takes a function as its parameters, you are passing a bunch of code without wrapping it inside a function.

Writing code dynamically is hard, dynamic ids are harder. Ban ids, innerHTML and inline eventlisteners, see how to manipulate documents and how to use event delegation with addEventListener.

With document.querySelector(".grid").innerHTML = "" you clear the list. There is no code that re-populates the list on the page after a deletion happened. Moreover document.getElementById("${auto_id}") will try to access a DOM element that is no longer there, as you cleared the grid.
Some other comments:

Don't put a script inside a onclick attribute. This is bad practice. Instead create a function with that logic, and call the function.

It is also better practice to attach event handlers via code, not via onclick attributes.

Declare your variables, like html, with const, let or var, otherwise they are implicitly declared as global variables.

i will in general no longer be the index of the deleted element, as you might have deleted other elements before it it, which would mean its index has decreased. You need a different way to identify the index of the item being deleted. One way to do this, is to always re-display the whole list after every deletion (like you do for every addition).

Using a unique id for each button is not best practice. By attaching an event handler to a delete-button using addEventListener, you can use the value of i without any need of an HTML attribute.

CSS grid is nice, but the percentages for the column widths will not work well when you reduce the width of your browser: for example, text will flow out of the delete button. It is better to use max-content for determining the width of a grid column.


Here is a possible implementation:


const store = [];
// Get all DOM element references
const todoNameInput = document.querySelector(".input");
const todoDateInput = document.querySelector(".date");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".action");
const container = document.querySelector(".grid");

// Bind event handlers via code only
addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    store.push({ todo: todoNameInput.value, date: todoDateInput.value });
    // Separate the logic for the display in a function
    displayList();
});

function displayList() {
    container.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
        const elemName = document.createElement("div");
        const elemDate = document.createElement("div");
        const delButton = document.createElement("button");

        elemName.textContent = store[i].todo;
        elemDate.textContent = store[i].date;
        delButton.textContent = "Delete";
        // Bind event handlers via code
        delButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            store.splice(i, 1); // We have the index!
            displayList(); // Re-display the whole list
        });

        container.append(elemName);
        container.append(elemDate);
        container.append(delButton);
    }
}
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content ;
}
.grid div {
    padding: 5px;
}
<p>Todo list</p>
<input class="input" placeholder="Todo name">
<input type="date" class="date">
<button class="action">Add</button>
<div class="grid"></div>




Can you recommend me a place to learn about event handlers?

Maybe start at mdn: Events
